# DrawText along a shape ( with Geometry) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I've two geometry-based shape, one like this one [image], and the other is text; (I have geometry coordinates for both.
I like To draw Text along that geometry in WPF with C#.
Like this:
[image]

How can i get that?

Comment: Did you tried putting two controls inside a grid? something like      <Grid><Path/><TextBlock/></Grid>. My idea is put them in a Grid and take advantage of Z-ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, though there is no easy way to do it (not that i know of, anyway). Check this article for solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263097.aspx